# How do I generate all possible MSTs of a graph using any algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

For an un-directed graph, how do I obtain all possible Minimum spanning trees?

A graph is created with set of Vertices V, and set of edges E.
In the below graph, we can see that there are two MSTs. I want to obtain all such MSTs (using any algorithm).

[image: MSTs for a given Graph]

I have currently tried to solve this using Kruskal's algorithm. But the algorithm will only give one MST.

```
 procedure Kruskal(G)
 A = {} //Empty
 foreach v belongs to G.Vertex
   MAKE-SET(v)
 foreach (u, v) in G.E ordered by weight(u, v), increasing:
   if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v):
     A = A ∪ {(u, v)}
     UNION(u, v)

 return A
```

Can I tweak the above algorithm to obtain desired solution, or is there any other algorithm to do so?

Comment: Also, note that there could be exponentially many minimum spanning trees ($n^{n-2}$ if all weights are the same).

Comment: See if [this link](https://tkramesh.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/does-kruskal-produce-all-msts/) helps.

Comment: I looked at this before, it tells me that Kruskal will help me find all possible MSTs. But how/where in the pseudo code of Kruskal must I bring the suggested changes for desired result?